# Xpath or CSS : Trying to create either one

Tags: xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to capture `"Featured Courses"` using either an xpath or CSS selector on the following link qaclickacademy website. Below is what I have tried.

```
By.xpath("//div[contains(concat(" ",normalize-space(@class), 'text-center'), " Test ")]");
```

Would you like to help me, please?

Comment: Share HTML code for the same

Answer (score 0):

If you use the xpath `//ul[@class="gallery course-list"]` you'll get all the `li`containing courses.

If you want the link in each `a` element you should try this:

```
//ul[@class="gallery course-list"]//a/@href
```

Comment: By title=By.xpath("//ul[@class='gallery course-list']//a/@href  ......I did this and it has an error.

Comment: What error did you get?
Also, try removing the /@href at the end of the xpath.